# Exchange data across Cloud Foundry orgs

Tags: cloud-foundry

Our Pivotal Cloud Foundry installation is separated into several organizations (orgs). I am looking for a way to exchange data between apps running in separate orgs via services like Redis or RabbitMQ.

a) What would be the proper way to create a "shared" service instance of Redis or RabbitMQ that can be reached from separated orgs and spaces?

b) How would credentials be provided for accessing the shared service instance for the individual spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is an external service for each of the orgs - you can add it via CUPS to both instances within different orgs.

Actual Redis/RabbitMQ service instance could be hosted separately or deployed/bound to interim/service app instance using existing service brokers.

Comment: I would like to use a Redis/RabbitMQ instance which is managed by Cloud Foundry. So I created a a service instance of Redis and bound it to an app in org A. Then I created a user provided service and added the properties found in the VCAP variables. But now I get this exception:  org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.service.common.RedisServiceInfo

Comment: This is the right answer.  There's no formal way to share things across an org, so you can hack around that using a user-provided service.  User provided services are not the same as a broker provided service though.  The metadata is slightly different, so auto detection or how you extract the info from VCAP_SERVICES will differ.  That's likely why you're seeing that error.  That or a typo.  Check you copied the properties and values over exactly.  You can run `cf env <app>` to look at VCAP_SERVICES and compare between the two apps.

Comment: Right, the Spring Cloud Connector was expecting a different format for the connection uri. We fixed it and it works now. One thing we are wondering: we connect to the Redis instance via it's IP address. How stable is the IP address? Is it possible to map a route to the Redis instance and use that one instead of the ip address?

Comment: Your Redis instance service should keep the IP during its lifetime and you can add custom dns name using your own dns servers.

CF routes are for apps and could be used if you are using an application gateway with service-mapped redis instance.

Comment: Thank you for the info @AnatolyKern . I was able to get in touch with a Pivotal architect in the meanwhile. He confirmed as well, that the IP address should be stable. He additionally recommended to use service keys as described here for this scenario: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/service-keys.html

Comment: Thanks for the service key info, would be good to know if it is going to work with your scenario.

On an url side: I would reiterate my statement. You can also use routes with service instance shared between the organisations by mapping to a shared url per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#route-binding

Comment: I was looking at route services as well. From my understanding this can only be used for app instances and is intended to route requests over indermediate services before they reach their actual service target. Useful for cross-cutting concerns like authentication, logging, caching, etc. Might be wrong here. Were you able to map a route successfully to a marketplace service instance, yet?

Comment: cf bind-route-service is specifically designed for mapping routes to service instances but I never tried it on marketplace service instances.

will try once I get a hand on the environment (something like  cf bind-route-service DOMAIN --hostname sharedservice serviceinstance)

Comment: Anyone using Sharing Service Instances for this purpose? https://docs-cloudfoundry-staging.cfapps.io/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html

Comment: little off topic, Is service sharing recommended way? shall multiple apps share common service or they should bind to their own version of service instance(1-1 mapping)